# How to implement POST request in custom services module?

Tags: hooks, commerce

I want to send the `POST` parameters from my PHP client library, for that how to make my custom services module?

```
function module_rest_services_resources() {
  return array(
   'new_note' => array(
         'retrieve' => array(
           'help' => 'Retrieves a note',
           'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'module_rest'),
           'callback' => '_module_rest_retrieve',
           'access callback' => '_module_rest_access',
           'access arguments' => array('view'),
           'access arguments append' => TRUE,
           'args' => array(
             array(
               'name' => 'id',
               'type' => 'int',
               'description' => 'The id of the note to get',
               'source' => array('path' => '0'),
               'optional' => FALSE,
             ),
           ),
         ),
     ),
  );
}
```

Its working with `GET` request, what i have to change here to process the `POST`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change into the POST request. You just change the source of resource from **path** to **data**. For example:

```
function module_rest_services_resources() {
  return array(
  'new_note' => array(
     'actions' => array(
       'retrieve' => array(
         'help' => 'Retrieves a note',
         'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'module_rest'),
         'callback' => '_module_rest_retrieve',
         'access callback' => '_module_rest_access',
         'access arguments' => array('view'),
         'access arguments append' => TRUE,
         'args' => array(
           array(
             'name' => 'id',
             'type' => 'int',
             'description' => 'The id of the note to get',
             'source' => array('data' => 'id'),
             'optional' => FALSE,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this sample, i have send parameter id from client. But  i have faced the error `Status 404 : Could not found controller`.

Comment: You should clear cache/rebuild menu. By the way. What web service client did you use?

Comment: I used Firefox poster to send request. After cleared the cache also am facing the same error. `Status 404 : Could not found controller`

Comment: In order create the POST parameters. You must create parameters in **Parameters tab** of Poster and Click on **Body from Parameters** in **Content to set** tab

Comment: Yes, I did like that only, but it send the parameter in **GET** only. I don't know whether it send **POST** data, but am facing the same error again

Comment: Can you add the **actions** in the **resource**. Check again my code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'action' for post request. For example:

```
<?php
/*
* Implementation of hook_services_resources()
*/
function custom_services_services_resources(){
    return array(
    'new_note' => array(
    'actions' => array(
    'note' => array(
    'help' => 'Retrieves a note',
             'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'custom_services'),
             'callback' => 'custom_services_rest_retrieve',
             'access callback' => 'custom_services_custom_access',
             'access arguments' => array('view'),
             'access arguments append' => TRUE,
             'args' => array(
               array(
                 'name' => 'id',
                 'type' => 'int',
                 'description' => 'The id of the note to get',
                 'source' => array('data' => 'id'),
                 'optional' => FALSE,
                ),
              ),
    ),
    ),
    )

    );

    }
```

In this,Then you need to enable that action in your rest service at backend. 
you need to call your service as like below
http://YOURSITE/SERVICE-END-POINT/new_note/note
Please check [this post](http://phpgainers.com/content/creating-post-request-in-custom-service-using-drupal-services-module) for more information